# Rule-based node creation: commerce product + product display node set

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-type, drupal-commerce, drupal-rules

I'm trying to bind a Commerce product type to my own custom type node (serving as a display node). The goal is to enter new data in as few places as possible. I'm therefore  exploring a rule-based creation of one type upon creation of the other. Seems like both directions are working. Of the two though, I prefer automatic creation of a Commerce Product upon user creation of Custom Type node, which will then serve as a product display.

I was wondering if anyone has been through this choice and could recommend this. Also, is the commerce_product_display_manager module necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce Product Display Manager is not necessary, I've gotten this to work and I've never used that module.

I went for the route of automatically creating a Node after saving the Product.

Below is my Rules export for this:

```
{ "rules_create_product_display" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create Product Display",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_product_insert" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "commerce-product:type" ], "value" : "**PRODUCT_TYPE**" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "**NODE_TYPE**",
            "param_title" : "[commerce-product:title]",
            "param_author" : [ "commerce-product:creator" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:**PRODUCT_REFERENCE**" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-product" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You'll need to substitute your own values for:

- **PRODUCT_TYPE** (product type that has been created)
- **NODE_TYPE** (node type being created)
- **PRODUCT_REFERENCE** (field that will reference the created product)

Sorry I can't dedicate more time to a better answer now, let me know if you'd like me to elaborate on the process of creating the above using the GUI

Answer (score 2):

The above example was useful but here is a more specific one:

```
{ "rules_create_product_display_on_product_creation" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create Product Display on Product creation",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_product_insert" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-product" ], "type" : "commerce_product" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "product_display",
            "param_title" : "[commerce-product:title]",
            "param_author" : [ "commerce-product:creator" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:field-product:0" ],
          "value" : [ "commerce-product" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The only problem I had was with the second action ("data_set")- it was important to select "entity-created:field-product:0", not the "entity-created:field-product" to make it work because we want to assign specific product and not a list of products.

This example is using the standard product display node type (product_display) but you can change it with the one you are using. Also have in mind that this is working only for one product type - for every product type a separated rule should be created. You may create also a rule for deleting the product display node when deleting the product.
This rule is useful only when you have connection one product-one product display. If you need to add more products per product display (colors, images with different prices) then you have to use [Commerce Bulk Product Creation](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_bpc) module.